# How to display average for only 1 numeric column using groupby

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a CSV file that I put into a data frame. This CSV file has 2 numeric columns called `tires` and `effort`. I'm trying to get the average grouped by another column (car make). This is what I came with but it keeps outputting to show the average for both "tires" and "effort":

```py
df_vehicles.groupby(['car make']).mean()
```

If I wanted to display the average for `effort` only and by vehicle make, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The groupby result is a dataframe, so you can select a column in your interests as follow:

```
df_grouped = df_vehicles.groupby(['car make']).mean()
df_grouped['effort']
```

Answer (score 0):

df_vehicles.groupby(['car make']).agg(avg_effort = ('effort','mean'))